# Multiple object detection and tracking simultaneously using SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, vuforia

I'm following the example project from here: https://github.com/yshrkt/VuforiaSampleSwift

I was able to increase the number of simultaneous image targets it tracks by adding the following line in the initTracker() method in VuforiaManager.mm:

Vuforia::setHint(Vuforia::HINT_MAX_SIMULTANEOUS_IMAGE_TARGETS, 4);

The example project can detect multiple image targets at the same time simultaneously but can track only one object and showing a 3d SceneKit object as  the tracking object. How can we track multiple object at the same time and show multiple SceneKit object simultaneously at the same time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this for Vuforia+SceneKit(simultaneous object detection) ...

https://github.com/zihad2010/-Vuforia-SceneKit-simultaneous-object-detection-